# Float to date in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby, date

We have a script that saves some rows in a table and one of them is filled with `Time.now.to_f`. So we have values like:

1330017921.1065
1330018520.80347

Is there a way to convert this to a date directly in MySQL I now I can use `Time.at` but I need a row mysql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess this is a microtime.

if you don't need milliseconds, you could query something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datefield = FROM_UNIXTIME(rounded_unixtime)
```

where rounded_unixtime would be in your case 1330017921